# Bash Value Too Great For Base, cant use date in if statement

Tags: bash

I have seen similar situations but couldn't really figure out how to correctly apply the suggested solutions to my situation.

I have a bash script with the following lines:

```
LAST=$(ssh root@host ls /backup3/mycomp/partition1/ | tail -1)
    #get last backup dir (formatted YYYY-MM-DD/). If none exist then get yesterdays Date
    if [[ -z "$LAST" || "$LAST" -eq "$TODAY" ]]
            then
                    log "/backup3/$HOST/$NAME/ does not exist, probably first backup or second backup done today."
                    LAST="$YESTERDAY"
    fi
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
[[: 2014-11-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

because I am actually searching for physical directory names, I cant just remove the zero. How would I go about making this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
if [[ -z "$LAST" || "$LAST" -eq "$TODAY" ]]
```

With:

```
if [[ -z "$LAST" || "$LAST" == "$TODAY" ]]
```

Since dates are not valid numbers, you want to do string comparison (`==`) not numeric comparison (`-eq`).

#### Discussion

Observe:

```
$ [[ "10-1" -eq "9" ]] && echo True
True
$ [[ "6+3" -eq "9" ]] && echo True
True
```

In the numeric context, signaled `-eq`, the shell is doing arithmetic on the arguments.  This means that, for your date 2014-11-08, the shell was taking `2014`, subtracting `11`, and then trying to subtract `08`.  The shell treats any number that begins with a `0` as octal.  Since `08` is not a valid octal number, you received an error message.

#### Comparison of `[` and `[[`

As Jonathan Leffler points out, the implied arithmetic feature of `[[` is another subtle difference between the old `[` and the newer `[[`.  Observe:

```
$ [[ "6+3" -eq "9" ]] && echo True
True
$ [ "6+3" -eq "9" ] && echo True
bash: [: 6+3: integer expression expected
```

The implied arithmetic feature of `[[` is not present in `[`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Its little things like this that keep me humble xD

Comment: That all adds up to another reason not to trust the `[[` operator, or subtracts from its usefulness because it does things which you wouldn't expect and may not want.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is very true. I initially assumed and expected the == to be the numerical operator and the -eq to be used for strings.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My reasons for avoiding `[[` are two-fold. The first is POSIX incompatibility.  The second is that, for ease of learning and using, languages should be _consistent_. By having a separate set of quoting rules inside `[[`, even if those quoting rules are 'better,' it adds to inconsistency and surprise.  Do you have other reasons for distrusting `[[`?

Comment: Those are two primary reasons, especially the inconsistency.  One other aspect which I don't trust is that sometimes the RHS of the `==` operator is a shell glob pattern.  (_When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern…_)  I'm also not keen on the special-casing of identifiers without the `$` prefix in arithmetic `(( … ))` operations; I would far rather have consistency than special cases to remember.